# How to expand a LinearLayout when clicked on?

Tags: android

I am new to android, I have arranged five LinearLayouts in a horizontal way, if I click the first first LinearLayout it  will expand and the other layouts remain in the same position, please help me.

This is the layout design :

[image: Layout Design]

Comment: Which way do you want to expand your layout? What have you tried before and not working? Be more specific please...

Comment: Are you asking something like [expanded list](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) ?

Comment: yes.. similar to that like horizontal listview.

Comment: Try to toggle the view. First set the Parent layout height as wrap_content, then hide the view which you want to expand. While click the parent view just visible the hidden layout. It automatically expand its view

Comment: Please suggest some example ??

Answer (score 0):

As the way you stated, I suggest you to use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

You can see for tutorial [HERE](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Comment: instead of listview i have to use 5 linearlayouts horizonatally

Comment: you can use custom expendablelistview.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new, you're gonna have to learn anyway. Since the functionality you're looking for can be easily implemented using a Horizontal ListView, I suggest you try this approach rather than using five LinearLayouts. ListViews have extensive controls. I recommend this implementation from experience : [HorizontalVariableListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView). Hope this helps!